# Upgraded GMail Storage - Not Showing?

Tags: gmail, online-storage

I have paid for the upgrade of Gmail to 25GB because my account has reached the 10GB limit. However, it still shows 10GB limit and that I am out of space. In my google account is says I have the 25GB of data. What is going on here and how do I get gmail to 25GB once I have paid for the additional storage?

Comment: How recently did you do it - apparently "it's normal to experience a delay of up to 24 hours before purchased storage is added to your account."

Comment: It is now fixed. I wish Google would make that apparent (the 24 hours) when you upgrade. I never saw that anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted on the [Purchase Extra Storage](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1047457) help page:

> It's normal to experience a delay of up to 24 hours before purchased
>   storage is added to your account

This isn't immediately obvious if you upgrade just for GMail, since it is in the Account support section.